# how to handle select boxes in django admin with large amount of records

Tags: python, django, django-admin, bigdata

my app has grown so that that drop downs in the django admin have 100,000s of options.  I can't even open my admin anymore because of its load on the database, not too mention I wouldn't be able to find an option in the select box.

Does django have an autocomplete option?

What is the best option for handling big data in django admin?

Answer (score 15):

Django 2.0 has introduced a new feature on the admin site, called [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields), which is helpful for models with foreign keys. It replaces the normal `<select>` element with an autocomplete element:

```
 class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     ordering = ['date_created']
     search_fields = ['question_text']

 class ChoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     autocomplete_fields = ['question']
```

Here's a screenshot of the element:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Will this not load all the objects into memory at the same time? Or does the auto_complete only load the best matches to the search term?

Answer (score 5):

Use raw_id_fields, like this:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('problematic_field', )
```

You can read more about this, here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

Basically - it will change the select boxes with raw id field with a lens icon - which open another window to make changes.

Answer (score 4):

There is many solutions to your problem out there but here is two ways I consider as viable:

1. If you need a built-in solution where you don't want to involve an external library, [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) may help you. This is from the documentation:

> By default, Django’s admin uses a select-box interface () for
>   fields that are ForeignKey. Sometimes you don’t want to incur the
>   overhead of having to select all the related instances to display in
>   the drop-down.
>
> raw_id_fields is a list of fields you would like to change into an
>   Input widget for either a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("newspaper",)
```

2. Use an auto-complete widget. There is ton of existing packages, see this [list](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/auto-complete/). Be careful to look which one has recent commits, it will give you an idea of the community awarness.